# asp.net hosting

Tags: asp.net

anyone know if theres a plan at discountasp.net for just a month and not a yearly plan? Because when i try to sign up for only a month, they only seem to have a plan for a year.

Answer (score 1):

I use CrystalTech myself. If you have a question about the plans at discountasp.net, why not contact them?